# Want to create a multilingual javascript object, how to handle if lots of labels?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a javascript file for multilingual functionality

i.e. display the error message in the correct language.

If I have allot of labels for a page, error messages, etc., what is a smart way of making this so the actual output on the page isn't huge?

**i guess the best way is to somehow output the labels that I need ONLY?**

```
lang.getkey('username');
```

will output the correct label, depending on the language.

Comment: You've asked 568 questions, and have only accepted answers on **42%** of them. That equates to a lot of time that people have spent helping you that you haven't bothered to acknowledge as helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language detection is usually done server-side by checking the `Accept-Language` HTTP header that is sent.

Browsers have limited, non-standardized means for identifying a user's language (with the exception of IE running on Windows).  With IE on Windows, you can access `navigator.userLanguage` or `navigator.systemLanguage`, which will return the operating system's [RFC #4646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4646) language-COUNTRY code.  Other browsers (Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox) provide `navigator.language`, which is in the same format with the exception of Opera which returns the language only.  In many cases this might be good enough, but it's still recommended to use a server solution.

I achieved something like this a while ago by separating the strings into different lang.js files and added the script to the document using `document.write()`.  The function would simply fetch the string from an array defined in that lang.js file.  A basic example might be:

```
// Get the language-COUNTRY code, and strip it to the language part only
var lang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage).substring(0,2);
var file = "lang/" + lang + ".js";

document.write('<script src="'+lang+'" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
```

This would ensure that only the strings for the necessary language were loaded, although I haven't included a fallback method here, you would need one for defaulting to a language when an unsupported one was detected.  You could do this by having a list of supported languages in an array, check to see if `lang` exists and if it doesn't, write a default script `src` instead.

Not to sound like a broken record, but you should probably be determining languages and including files server side, not client side.

Comment: yes I am determining it server side, that is why I was going to init the lang object via server side code that returns the 'data'.